# Create concatenated neural network and how to train it

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, concatenation, text-classification

I have a question about input-shapes for a concatenated neural network. I have a text column that is tokenized and with the function pad_sequences all data points have length 2395 and for training I have 6493 data points. So the shape for the text part is (6493, 2395), isn't it? I have 17 additional columns that I want to put into the model. So the shape of this additional data is (6493, 17).

For the neural network I have the following code:

```
embedding_dim = 300
inp_dim = X_train.shape[1]
text_data = Input(shape=(max_length,), name="X_train")
meta_data = Input(shape=X_train_zusatz.shape, name="X_train_zusatz")

x1 = (Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, output_dim=embedding_dim, input_length=max_length))(text_data)
x2 = (LSTM(300, dropout = 0.2, recurrent_dropout = 0.2, return_sequences=True))(x1)
x3 = (Dense(300, activation = "relu"))(meta_data)
x4 = concatenate([x2, x3], axis = 1)
x5 = (Dense(300, activation = "relu"))(x4)
x6 = Dropout(0.25)(x5)
x7 = (Dense(300, activation = "relu"))(x6)
x8 = BatchNormalization()(x7)
x9 = (Dense(4, activation='softmax'))(x8)

model = Model(inputs = [text_data, meta_data], outputs = x9)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])

print(model.summary())
```

The model.summary looks like the following:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
X_train (InputLayer)            (None, 2395)         0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_19 (Embedding)        (None, 2395, 300)    23400600    X_train[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
X_train_zusatz (InputLayer)     (None, 6493, 17)     0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_19 (LSTM)                  (None, 2395, 300)    721200      embedding_19[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_44 (Dense)                (None, 6493, 300)    5400        X_train_zusatz[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_18 (Concatenate)    (None, 8888, 300)    0           lstm_19[0][0]                    
                                                                 dense_44[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_45 (Dense)                (None, 8888, 300)    90300       concatenate_18[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)             (None, 8888, 300)    0           dense_45[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_46 (Dense)                (None, 8888, 300)    90300       dropout_1[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_7 (BatchNor (None, 8888, 300)    1200        dense_46[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_47 (Dense)                (None, 8888, 4)      1204        batch_normalization_7[0][0]      
==================================================================================================
Total params: 24,310,204
Trainable params: 24,309,604
Non-trainable params: 600
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
None
```

So my question is, why I cannot see the number of data points (6493) after the embedding layer. Do I made any mistake at this layer? Becaue in the dense layer I got the shape (None, 6493, 300) but in the embedding layer I got (None, 2395, 300). I am afraid, that columns and rows are mixed here, is that right?

Besides that, I cannot train the model. The code:

```
model.fit([X_train, X_train_zusatz], y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=500, validation_data=[[X_test, X_test_zusatz], y_test], class_weight=class_weight)
```

will lead to the error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected X_train_zusatz to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (6493, 17)
```

How can I solve that? Because (6493, 17) is the right shape for the additional data, but my neural network will not take it.

Thank you so much!

Best regards, Daniel

Answer (score 0):

you are using LSTM layer which need 3 dimension input but as you know your input is 2 dimension. dont use LSTM but use Dense instead.

Comment: But before the lstm layer is called, there ist the word embedding. The output for the word embedding should have dim 3, so the lstm layer should work, is that wrong?